# Use username from one class in another class in python

Tags: python, oop

I am using different classes in a program, in which a user logs within the 'Main' class, and then this username is then used for functions in a different class to which they are redirected to. However I am having trouble moving the inputted username to the next class that is loaded up. Any help is appreciated.

```
 def TeachLoginFunc(loginscreen, username, password):
        if username == ""  or password == "":
            ms.showerror("Error","Make sure no fields are empty")
        else:
            while True:
                with sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db') as db:
                    cursor = db.cursor()
                find_user = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND usertype = 'Teacher'")
                cursor.execute(find_user, (username.get(), password.get()))
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                if results:
                    for i in results:
                        Label(loginscreen, text = "Log-in successful!", fg = "GREEN", font = "Calibri").pack()
                        Teachmenu.teachmain(loginscreen)
                else:
                    Main.logindestroy(loginscreen)
                    ms.showerror("Error", "Incorrect Details")
                    Main.login(screen1)
```

and this is how I have created the second class:

```
class Teachmenu(Main):
    def __init__(self, screen1, StudName, var_classname, var_classnamedel, var_studname):
        super().__init__(Main)
        screen1 = Main.screen1
        self.StudName = StudName
        self.var_classname = var_classname
        self.var_classnamedel = var_classnamedel
        self.var_studname = var_studname
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of two classes **A** and **B**. Class **A** has an attribute *name*. The *name* attribute of an **instance** of **A** can then be passed to an **instance** of class **B**. These instances are respectively called *a* and *b*:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)

a = A('Anteino')
b = B()
b.setName(a.name)
b.printName()
```